# Codeigniter view returned as a string with data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter 3 and im trying to pull in a view to a variable, and pass data to the view for inclusion. But the view is not recognising the data being passed and is telling me the variable doesn't exist.

This is how I'm calling the view:

```
$view = $this->load->view('notifications/' . $report_type, $data ,true);
```

And then in the view I'm trying to loop through $data and display as appropriate, like so:

```
foreach($data as $item){
    // echo stuffs
}
```

I know $data definately contains data as I've var_dump'ed it.

Can I do it like this?

Comment: what is `$report_type` and `$data` ??

Comment: $report_type is the name of the view and $data is my data

Comment: `$data` is array or a single variable.

Comment: $data is an array

Comment: how you set up this array? post full code

Comment: I don't need help with the array or data, or the setup of the controller etc, thats all fine. I need to know if I can pass data to a view that I am pulling as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass an associative array to the loader.

```
$view = $this->load->view('notifications/' . $report_type, array('data' =>$data) ,true);
```

Now the variable will be visible at the view.

Comment: Please educate the OP on how the $data variable itself is not passed to the view directly, but rather its keyvalue pairs.

Answer (score 0):

if model Page_m and method western return a specific value which you need,

```
$this->data['western'] =$this->Page_m->western();
$this->load->view('notifications/' . $report_type,$this->data);
```

in your view

```
foreach($western as $item){
    // echo stuffs
}
```